# HTML5/CSS3: image as flex item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add image to the flex item, but i am not able to fit it to the complete div container.

following is my code. can someone advise how can i have image fit in to flex item (div container).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Flex Box</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .flex-container {

            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            width: 800px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: blueviolet;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-align-content: stretch;
            align-content: stretch;
            -webkit-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }

        .flex-item {
            background-color: bisque;
            margin: 15px;
            width: 600px;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .third_item {
            -webkit-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
        }

        #iimage {
            background-color: transparent;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <article class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item third_item">
            <img src="block_beach_1.jpg" width="600px" height="100px" id="iimage">
        </div>
    </article>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML/CSS

Comment: i have just added the code.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** supply a screen shot of your code. Add all of your code directly to the question as _**text**_. This will assist SO users to assist you in a more technical capacity. It is unlikely anyone will want to manually rewrite your code to solve this.

Comment: just edited to add the code in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit the image to the container by specifying a `width` `100%` in your css for the image. Also remove the inline width and height property for the image.

Edit: If you want to fit the image horizontally and vertically, apply `height` `100%` along with the width value.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: bisque;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 600px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.third_item {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

#iimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<article class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item third_item">
    <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*MI686k5sDQrISBM6L8pf5A.jpeg" id="iimage" />
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It's leaving space in bottom

Comment: If you want to fit the image horizontally and vertically, apply height 100% along with the width value. -- Please check now.

Comment: Can I know why this was down voted? Please mention if there are any mistakes so that we could correct as well